# create dynamic styles in ttk widgets

Tags: tkinter, ttk, ttkwidgets

I would like to create dynamic styles for labels that can have 4 background options, but the style function does not accept lambda, or functions in general, how could I dynamically switch the unique styles of my layout

Create styles

```py
        self.style.configure('Club.TLabel',background='green') # Club card color 
        self.style.configure('Diamond.TLabel',background='blue') # Diamond card color 
        self.style.configure('Heart.TLabel',background='red') # Heart card color
```

Try to add a config with dynamic style

```py
        def handleCardStyle(card):
            if 'c' in card:
                return 'Club.TLabel'
            elif 'd' in card:
                return 'Club.TLabel'
            elif 'h' in card:
                return 'Diamond.TLabel'

        self.firstHeroCard = Label(self.tableContainner,text='Ac',anchor=CENTER)
        self.firstHeroCard.configure(style=lambda: handleCardStyle('Ac'))
        self.firstHeroCard.place(relx=0.5,rely=1,relwidth=0.1,relheight=0.2,anchor=SE)
```

Comment: You don't need `lambda` since you want the value at the time the widget is created. Just call the function `style=handleCardStyle('Ac')`.

Comment: that's it, I can use after to change text, and change style ty!